# Redux remote devtools run at localhost

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am using React Native with Redux remote devtools.

with this code, the devtools works well:

```
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({realtime: true });
const store = createStore(AppReducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(middleware),
));
```

The devtools should be listening to my local ip address xx.xx.xx:8097 by default.

Now, I wish to change it to localhost:8000. Referring to the document site https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools, I changed the codes to:-

```
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
    realtime: true,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8000
});
const store = createStore(AppReducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
   applyMiddleware(middleware),
));
```

but now, the devtool is no longer working anymore. Even I change the devtool settings by ticking "Use custom (local) server" with Host name "localhost" and Port "8000" cannot help.

Actually what steps I have missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have forgotten the hostname tag:

```js
{
    realtime: true,
    'localhost',
    port: 8000
}
```

Should probably be:

```js
{
    realtime: true,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8000
}
```

Comment: oh, yes, I missed it in the question, but even I added it to my codes it did not work.